# Can I switch activity with tab action bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have some different activities with different layout, and I use an action bar in Tab mode. So I would pass from an activity to another when I select a tab in action bar.

How can i do?? Have you any suggest??

I would someting as:

In `ActionBar.TabListener` when I switch tab, I call: `startActivity(new Intent(context, theNewActivity);`

is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at ApiDemos samples in Android SDK

Comment: which sample in particularly??

Answer (score 2):

> How can i do?

The old model of having activities inside of tabs was never a good idea IMHO and now is deprecated.

Either change those activities to be fragments (and switch between them using tabs in the action bar), or get rid of the tabs and choose some other navigation model that does not involve tabs.

> In ActionBar.TabListener when I switch tab, I call: startActivity(new Intent(context, theNewActivity);

If you think this will open up `theNewActivity` *inside* the tab, no, that will not work. You can certainly call `startActivity()` based upon a tab being clicked, but the UX probably is not what you want and even less likely to be what users want.